# MvcSiteMapProvider renders wrong level if requested level is "empty"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I currently render two levels of menu using the method

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(2,1,true)
```

for the 2nd level.

What I THINK I'm saying in this case is "show me all level 2 nodes that are related to the current path". The last param is "allowForwardSearch" and I don't know what that means, I just know that if I don't set it to true, I get nothing rendered.

As it is, this renders the 2nd level menu just fine UNLESS all of the 2nd level nodes are filtered out via security/visibility filters which would leave an empty list of nodes for the 2nd level. If the expected result is NO 2nd level nodes, then it renders 1st level nodes instead. Which winds up duplicating items from the 1st level menu. I would expect that it would just render nothing, but that's not the case.

Is this a bug, or do I need to use a specific override (there's 80!) to get it to NOT revert to showing me 1st level nodes when I ask for 2nd level nodes.

Thanks.

Comment: I cross-posted your issue to [GitHub](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/348) because it appears to be a bug, not a question.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that has now been fixed in [v4.6.13](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/releases/tag/v4.6.13).

If you are using an earlier version, you can add an invisible dummy node to your SiteMap that your user accessibility to, which will override this behavior.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <!-- Level 1 -->
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About">
        <!-- Level 2 -->
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="About Me" controller="Home" action="AboutMe"/>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="About You" controller="Home" action="AboutYou" />
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dummy Node" url="/dummy-url?id=1" visibility="!*" 
            visibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Contact" controller="Home" action="Contact"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

The URL doesn't actually have to exist, you just need to specify it to override the routing behavior of the dummy node. If you need to do this in more than one place, you will need more than one dummy URL, though (since URLs must be unique) - for that I suggest incrementing the "id" query string parameter or changing the URL in some other way.

Note that you only need to specify the visibilityProvider explicitly if it isn't already configured as your default visibility provider.

What you stated about invisibility is incorrect - invisible nodes are not removed from the SiteMap API, only inaccessible nodes are. So if you have at least 1 invisible node there, the menu won't switch to being based on the root node when the user doesn't have access to any of the other configured nodes.